# Reading required values from Excel using python read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read excel by specific text and get corresponding values. I am reading excel using Pandas read_excel method. Output I get is Dictionary within List. I am not sure how to read values within Dictionary as I am learning python.

Here is the excel I am trying to read (I am just adding few rows). I want to read Code 'TYPECODE', 'BLADMFEE' and get values of it from Column D (5810947, Yes) and Column E (C308529, Yes)
[image]

I am using glob as there are lost of excel files in folder

```
pglist = [pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name=[0]) for x in p.glob("**/*.xlsx") if 
          x.name.startswith("PG")]
```

Output is in Dictionary within List. How can I convert dictionary to DataFrame and read values?

```
[{0:   Mapping Source   Code     Service Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0        Derived       TYPECODE      ID    5810947    C398529
1       Dervided       BLADMFEE      ID        Yes        Yes}]
```

Comment: You have a list of dicts of dataframes because you passed your sheet_name argument in as a list. Try `sheet_name=0` instead. From the docs: `sheet_name: [0, 1, "Sheet5"]: Load first, second and sheet named “Sheet5” as a dict of DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use pandas much but I think I know what you want to do

this my excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa4Km.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import json
path = "example1.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(path)
Datos = json.loads(data.to_json())
```

to get the "Code" column

```
Datos['Code']
```

answer:

```
{'0': 'TYPECODE', '1': 'BLADMFEE'}
```

and if you want one of the records

```
Datos['Code']['0']
```

answer:

```
'TYPECODE'
```

you must put the row number in quotes since `Datos['Code']` is still a dictionary

column D and E, since they do not have a name, will always start like this `"Unnamed:"` and the number of the corresponding column, which in our case is `"Unnamed: 3"` and `"Unnamed: 4"`

for column D it would be:

```
Datos['Unnamed: 3']
```

answer:

```
{'0': 5810947, '1': 'Yes'}
```

for column E it would be:

```
Datos['Unnamed: 4']
```

answer:

```
{'0': 'C398529', '1': 'Yes'}
```

I hope it helps you and you can understand me since I don't know English :)